# OpenCV - Parameters in Laplacian Filter (Java)

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I'm kind of new with opencv. I'm using Java and I'd like to know how to apply a Laplacian filter with alpha = 0.2, I mean, using this matrix to convolve:

```
0.1667    0.6667    0.1667
0.6667   -3.3333    0.6667
0.1667    0.6667    0.1667
```

I'm using this code, but I don't know what to use as "ddepth" and "ksize":

Imgproc.Laplacian(b, b_lapl, ddepth, ksize, 1, 0);

Is there any quick form of getting the abs of the result?

Answer (score -1):

> ddepth – Desired depth of the destination image.
>
> ksize – Aperture size used to compute the second-derivative filters. See getDerivKernels() for details. The size must be positive and odd.

from the manual: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#laplacian

Comment: I already read it but I didn't understood, that's why I'm asking